# pd.to_datetime converting the date into a wrong date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the data in the following format of,

> dd-mm-yyyy

[image]

After I run the following commands to get date,

```
df['result_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['result_date']) 
df['t0']=pd.to_datetime(df['t0'])
df['t1']=pd.to_datetime(df['t1'])
df['t0']=df['t0'].apply(lambda x : x.date())
df['t1']=df['t1'].apply(lambda x : x.date())
```

I am getting the following output:
[image]

The `pd.to_datetime` is converting '11/02/21' into '2021-11-02'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` follows the American convention when the format is ambiguous, where month is written before date. You can specify the format explicitly to make the format unambiguous

```py
In [1]: pd.to_datetime("11/02/21", format="%d/%m/%y")
Out[1]: Timestamp('2021-02-11 00:00:00')
```

Comment: You can also set keyword `dayfirst = True`